# Pool error while trying to send a chunks of messages to telegram bot asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, celery, python-asyncio, aiogram

I'am using Celery to run a chain of tasks that depends on each other inputs.

```
@app.task(queue="tasks")
def run_chain_tasks() -> None:
    tasks_chain: list[chain] = chain(
        fetch_cars_from_db.s(),
        compare_data_before_notifications.s(),
        create_tbot_notification.s(),
        send_tbot_notification.s(),
    )
    result: list[AsyncResult] = tasks_chain.apply_async()
    result.get()
```

for telegram messages I use `aiogram==3.2.0` for sending notifications to the bot

```
@app.task(queue="tasks", priority=2)
def create_tbot_notification(data: Dict[str, dict]) -> str:
    print('Create telegram notification...')

    notification_message = ''
    
    # In this function I build the message 
    # before passing it to the next in chain function

    return notification_message 


@app.task(
    queue="tasks", 
    priority=1,
    autoretry_for=(HTTPError, ConnectionError, BaseException,),
    default_retry_delay=5,
    retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 5}
)
def send_tbot_notification(message: str) -> None:
    asyncio.run(send_tbot_notification_coroutine(message))


async def send_tbot_notification_coroutine(message: str) -> None:
    print('Send notification...')
    try:
        if message != '':
            MESSAGE_LIMIT = 4096
            if len(message) > MESSAGE_LIMIT:
                msgs = [message[i:i + 4096] for i in range(0, len(message), 4096)]
                for text in msgs:
                    text.replace('-', '\-')
                    await bot.send_message(
                        chat_id=TELBOT_CHAT_ID, 
                        text=text,
                        parse_mode='HTML', 
                        disable_web_page_preview=True
                    )
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(
                    chat_id=TELBOT_CHAT_ID, 
                    text=message,
                    parse_mode='HTML', 
                    disable_web_page_preview=True
                )
        else:
            print('No results.')
    except Exception as exc:
        raise exc
```

The first time I run the function **run_chain_tasks** everything works fine and I get all the notifications.

The problem is when the second time hits, I get an error says:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 740, in call_at self._check_closed() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 519, in _check_closed raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`